# How to write query to retrieve between two Dates in a better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

This is my SQL query what I tried

```
SELECT 
    TransactionNumber,Time
FROM 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction]
WHERE 
    Time>='2015-01-01' and Time<='2015-12-31'
```

Total records returned 2.8 million. It's taking 10 seconds.

I created an index for `Time` and `TransactionNumber` as well.

Still what else I have to do get the rows faster than this?

Thanks

Comment: Please use internationally recognized measures like thousands, millions, billions - not regional ones ("lakhs") 
other people won't know what they mean ...

Comment: @CraigYoung both are in ASC order

Comment: @Craig I meant column order

Comment: @GurwinderSingh As i thoght it were two indexes, i posted my answer

Comment: @GurwinderSingh it's a single index with two column names and both are sorting by ASC

Comment: 2.8 million rows is ***a lot of data***! It's going to take a "long" time no matter what. If you want to improve it, return less data. 2 options might yield marginal improvement (1) `CLUSTERED` index on `Time` (2) Index on `Time INCLUDE (TransactionNumer)` ... but either way your problem is not the query/index, it's the amount of data.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Yes, column order on indexes is very important.

Comment: 2.8 million rows is not really a LOT of data, it's just not a small amount. If your data is going to continue to grow, consider partitioning it (e.g. per year), which would speed up access.

Comment: @JeffWatkins 2.8 million is not a lot for data stored in a table. But it is a lot to return in a single `SELECT` statement. What exactly would someone be doing with 2.8 million rows that 10 seconds is considered slow?

Comment: @CraigYoung This is not the result. Using whole year transaction number I have to calculate the total sales further.

Comment: @JeffWatkins I am just fetching only one year records here. I don't understand what are you really meant to say. Thanks

Comment: If the table continues to grow, it'll gradually take longer to retrieve records unless the index is clustered. In actuality, if you're performing this query a lot, you may want to consider pre-extracting the data into a data mart so subsequent access is much quicker. As Craig mentioned though, 10s for 2.8m rows isn't exactly slow.

Comment: @mohamed btw, I did a little benchmark test `SELECT TOP 2800000 IntCol, DateCol` from a table with only those 2 columns and 10 million rows. This is the fastest you could possibly achieve because there is no filtering, no extra processing - the query just returns the first 2.8 million rows it can find. Result: Server time to get the data `1 second`. Total elapsed time which includes sending the data to the SSMS client (on the same machine, a low-end laptop) and loading it into the grid: `10 seconds`. Conclusion, your query is probably fast enough on your hardware. Optimise elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

2.8 million rows is a lot of data! It's going to take a "long" (long being relative - 10 seconds is reasonable for 2.8 million rows) time no matter what. If you want to improve it, return less data.

There are 2 options that might yield marginal improvement:

- Create a `CLUSTERED` on the `Time` column. *Note a table is only allowed 1 clustered index. So this might not be a good when other factors are considered.*
- Create an index on `Time` that `INCLUDE`s `TransactionNumer`

But either way your problem is not the query/index, it's the amount of data.

---

## Additional Info

- Using 2 separate indexes as you have is not going to be of any help. Your query is only able to use 1 index (whichever it considers is best).
- I have assumed that your `TransactionNumber` really is a *numeric data type* and not one of the horrific "string numbers" I see far too often. If you are using some form of `varchar` to store your `TransactionNumber` you would do well to change that to `int` or `bigint`. These types require less bytes to store ==> meaning less data ==> meaning better performance.
- Your query currently has a bug unless you truncate the time portion of your `Time` column. Clearly you intend returning all transactions for the year. But currently you'll miss out on all transactions for the 31 December that did not happen at `00:00`. To fix this Time range queries should be filtered as follows:

  - `Time >= StartOfRange and Time < StartOfNextRange`
  - E.g. `Time >= '2015-01-01' and Time < '2016-01-01'`
  - NB: Note Strictly `<` in the second condition. This includes all transactions ***before*** the very beginning of the next year.

---

## Math

Some calculations on why I say 2.8 million rows is "a lot of data to return".

- You return `TransactionNumber` and `Time`. I'll assume 4 and 8 bytes per row respectively. (It could be more but this is a ***very conservative*** estimate.)
- That's `12 bytes * 2,800,000 = 33,600,000 bytes` (approximately 32 MB).
- This is just the minimum *data returned*. Bear in mind that the data processed is much more. Including other columns of your table and the index trees.
- To transfer 33.6 MB of data in 10 seconds between server and client would require: `32 MB * 8 / 10 = 25.6` I.e. an average transfer rate of well over 25 megabits per second.

---

## Conclusion

Whatever it is you're trying to do that requires 2.8 million rows possibly needs a rethink on your approach. However, if you're talking about a once/year job - then is 10 seconds really worth worrying about?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you put more of the calculations upfront in variables where they will only be executed once you'll get better performance. Probably won't make much of a difference, and may even be detrimental to performance, but interesting to try.

```
DECLARE @midwaySeconds int = DATEDIFF(s, '2015-1-1 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 23:59:59') / 2
DECLARE @midwayDate datetime2 = DATEADD(s, @midwaySeconds, '2015-1-1 00:00:00')
SELECT 
    TransactionNumber,Time
FROM 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction]
WHERE 
    ABS(DATEDIFF(s, Time, @midwayDate)) < @midwaySeconds
```

Comment: OP doesn't have any "calculations". `Time` is evaluated against 2 constant date-literals. Your suggested change actually ***adds*** a calculation on the `Time` column; which also makes the query [non-Sargable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/224704). As a result, it becomes impossible for the query to benefit from the correct index; It has to scan ***all rows***. (This is about the worst advice possible.)

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight on the performance hit taken when adding functions to where clauses. The non-Sargable link you included was very helpful.